Odoo 16: Calendar view - View definition invalid
In a custom Odoo16 module, I want to create this calendar view:
<record id="tc_work_day_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">tc.work.day.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">tc.work.day</field>
    <field name="type">calendar</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar date_start="date_start" date_end="date_end" color="company_id" mode="month">
            <field name="date_start"/>
            <field name="date_end"/>
            <field name="company_id"/>
        </calendar>
    </field>
</record>

When I want to install/upgrade this module, I have an error:
View definition tc.work.day.calendar invalid in lgr_TC/views/work_day.xml

View error context:
'-no context-'

I tried these things:

Put the calendar view in comment -> Form, tree and search views works but I don't have my view
Uninstall module and re-install it
Remove field "type"
Compare with a working module and all code is the same (except module name, view name, ...)


The error message indicates that there is an issue with the model name in your action definition (ir.actions.act_window record); the model name should be in the format module_name.model_name.

I tried but it doesn't work and all other views are made like this
